# R dataframe create One to One Relationship

Tags: r, dataframe, relationship

Experts, looking for some advice with the below R dataframe I need to build a relationship for each Zone's within particular city.

**Input:**

```
mydf = data.frame(City = c("LA", "LA", "LA", "NYC", "NYC"), 
           Zone = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2"))
```

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbFjb.png)

Comment: Is there a typo in the 2nd row of the output table? (A1, A2) is repeated twice. Should be (A1, A3) instead?

Comment: Yes, your're right. It should be (A1, A3)

Comment: you can almost get there using `melt(crossprod(table(mydf)))` , but to get your expected outcome you can use `temp <- crossprod(table(mydf)) ; diag(temp) <- NA ;  r <- reshape2::melt(temp, na.rm=TRUE) ; r[r$value==1, ]`

Comment: or to really stick with `graph` tools: `library(igraph) ; g <- simplify(graph_from_adjacency_matrix(crossprod(table(mydf)))) ; 
as_data_frame(g) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse approach that defines a function for combinations & applies it to each city's zones:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(purrr)

generate_combinations <- function(data){
  zone <- data %>% select(Zone) %>% unlist()
  combinations <- expand.grid(Zone_1 = zone, Zone_2 = zone) # generate all combinations
  combinations <- combinations %>% 
    filter(!(Zone_1 == Zone_2)) %>% # remove invalid combinations
    mutate_all(as.character)
  return(combinations)
}

mydf <- mydf %>% 
  nest(Zone) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, generate_combinations)) %>%
  unnest()

> mydf

  City Zone_1 Zone_2
1   LA     A2     A1
2   LA     A3     A1
3   LA     A1     A2
4   LA     A3     A2
5   LA     A1     A3
6   LA     A2     A3
7  NYC     B2     B1
8  NYC     B1     B2

# if City info is no longer needed
mydf <- mydf %>% select(-City)
```

Data:

```
mydf = data.frame(City = c("LA", "LA", "LA", "NYC", "NYC"), 
                  Zone = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly not the most efficient way to do things, but it will work and it's almost readable.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

output <- mydf %>%
  split(., f=mydf[, "City"]) %>%                   # Split into data.frames by "City"
  sapply(., function(x) use_series(x, Zone)) %>%   # Extract zones
  sapply(combn, 2) %>%                             # Find all combinations of size 2
  do.call("cbind", .) %>%                          # Combine them into a data frame
  t %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  rbind(., data.frame(V1=.$V2, V2=.$V1))           # Add it to the inverse, to get all possible combinations

colnames(output) <- c("Zone_1", "Zone_2")          # Rename columns



output
      Zone_1 Zone_2
1     A1     A2
2     A1     A3
3     A2     A3
4     B1     B2
5     A2     A1
6     A3     A1
7     A3     A2
8     B2     B1
```

Comment: Perfect. as expected. Thank you!!